# Http header в запросе через php

Tags: php, http

Как сделать запрос в php с добавлением http header? Требуется запрос по ссылке с указанием в http заголовке токена. Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Так же как без header, только с header. К вопросу лучше приложить код который вы уже написали

Comment: Можно через `curl`, можно и через `file_get_contents` в третий аргумент.

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо, дальше сам разобрался , все помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Например так, через CURL

```
 $headers = array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Token:'your_token')
    );

$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_close ($handle);
```